# Esp8266 nodemcu v3 connection to usb fingerprint scanner

Tags: arduino, communication, usb-device, io, nodemcu

My project is about making an ioT biometric attendance management using Esp8266 nodemcu and a Morpho usb biometric scanner.
So my question is whether  is it possible to connect a usb fingerprint scanner to esp8266 and send the data to Android app .Actually i want the fingerprint scanner should be connected to Esp8266 module which will act as Access point for Android app and send data to android device through wifi ?

I am attaching the picture of fingerprint scanner[image][image]

Comment: you would be better off using a pro micro or leo AVR board; one with a usb host capability. that mcu can talk to the ESP.

Comment: I want to make it possible with nodemcu and i found fingerprint library for nodemcu by adafruit now the question is after authentication the nodemcu should send boolean data to android app through wifi is it possible?

Comment: yes, that's possible, but you still cannot hook up that sensor to a nodeMCU without another controller that has USB hosting built-in. It _might_ be possible to bit-bang enough of the stack to read the fingerprint, but i'm betting that's beyond the scope, and would be hard to do with the not-real-time nodeMCU's shared CPU; making it very sporadic in its successes.

Comment: Any esp8266 development is capable of doing it other than uno,pro,micro or leo boards?? Because i want it to make as cheap and small as possible

Comment: an ESP01+pro micro will be about the same cost as a nodeMCU; slightly more, but it works, and the combo will be smaller than a nodeMCU

Comment: What about wemos d1? i saw this video he has done it with wemos d1

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=M1Q4dGaJKnM

Comment: [something like this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/112354400138) as seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxjLx5RdaSQ) can be likely be made to work with an ESP kit, the USB one would likely be (much) harder to wire.

Comment: What if i use usb to ttl converter for device

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I think it should be possible what you want to do. The big question is how to access the data of the sensor. Once you have them, implementing the part of providing this info online will be straightforward.

What the hardware concerns, the ESP8266 doesn't have any USB interface, but you can use a USB-to-UART converter IC (like the FT232) and use the UART interface of the ESP8266.

However, the question is how does the sensor use the USB interface and how does it send the measured data over it or what kind of info does it send. You'll have to study the datasheet, application notes and/or design guide of the sensor and find more information about this point.

Comment: Thank you for your positive response finally someone​ siad yes it is possible,

Comment: Now i am thinking that i would use sparkfun fingerprint library to verify the fingerprints .so can i code the nodemcu with the fingerprint library available on github??? Does nodemcu has that computational power?

Comment: That's a kind of question that is difficult to answer! Generally speaking, the ESP8266 doesn't have much computational power but it could be ok for your case. You have to try and find out. If it is not enough for you, consider having another processor that will do the interface to the sensor(s) and use the ESP8266 just for the wireless part.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=M1Q4dGaJKnM see this he has done it with wemos d1 board now whats the difference between nodemcu and wemos d1

Comment: `USB-to-UART converter IC (like the FT232)` Those don't work in the direction you are proposing. Those are USB peripherals not Hosts.